# How to extend Query object in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, mongoose

I'be trying to add a chain method to the Query object called "paginate". If I add it to query.js I can use it without any problems. However, it's not a good idea to modify one of the core files.

I'm using this code I found with some modifications and want it to be part of the Query prototype, but I haven't had any success on making it work out of Query.js.

How can I accomplish this? Are there any docs on how to extends any of these core files through a module? I haven't found anything that works for me.

```
mongoose.Query.prototype.paginate = function(page, limit, cb) {
  var model, query, skipFrom;
  if (page == null) {
    page = 1;
  }
  if (limit == null) {
    limit = 10;
  }
  query = this;
  model = this.model;
  skipFrom = (page * limit) - limit;
  query = query.skip(skipFrom).limit(limit);
  if (cb) {
    return query.run(function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err, null, null);
      } else {
        return model.count(query._conditions, function(err, total) {
          return cb(null, total, docs);
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error("pagination needs a callback as the third argument.");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a lot easier than what I expected. This is what I did and it worked:

Created a paginate.js file with:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Query.prototype.paginate = function(aPageStart, aLimit, aCallback) {
  var model, query;

  if (aLimit == null) {
    aLimit = 10;
  }
  query = this;
  model = this.model;
  query = query.skip(aPageStart).limit(aLimit);
  if (aCallback) {
    return query.run(function(aError, aDocs) {
      if (aError) {
        return aCallback(aError, null, null);
      } else {
        return model.count(query._conditions, function(aError, aTotal) {
          return aCallback(null, aTotal, aDocs);
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error("pagination needs a callback as the third argument.");
  }
};
```

and just require it where needed (In my model in this case).

Then you can call this method as the last of the chain.

Cheers,

Marcos.

Comment: Eek! that works...  but directly extending a library like this is generally considered dirty since the internals of the library might change version to version.  You could end up with a really broken method with a simple upgrade of the library.  Node libraries are notorious for big internal (and very often external) changes in libraries.  If you are willing to risk that breakage then fire away, but it might be safer to go with a "static".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this module or look how they achieve it: [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/)

Another solution is to create a method to your schema like that:

```
Schema.statics.paginate = (page, limit, cb) ->
   ...
  return query;
// or
Schema.statics.paginate = (query, page, limit, cb) ->
   ...
  return query.exec();
```

Comment: Yes. That's another way. However I wanted it to be part of the query object so it can be chained with other methods from query like find, sort, populate, gt, lt, etc...

So for example you would be able to do this from your Model(simplified):

this.find().gt().populate("Entity").sort().paginate(params) etc...

Answer (score 0):

The API to extend Mongoose schemas is `plugin()`. Define a simple plugin function like this:

```js
function paginatePlugin(schema) {
  schema.query.paginate = function({ start, limit = 10 }) {
    return this.skip(start).limit(limit);
  };
}
```

Then inject it into your model like:

```js
fooSchema.plugin(paginatePlugin);
```

Then use it:

```js
await Foo.find().paginate({ start: 10, limit: 100 });
```

This allows you to compose your query extensions, too:

```js
await Foo
  .find()
  .where({ bar: { $gt: 1 } })
  .sort({ bar: 1 })
  .paginate({ start: 10, limit: 100 });
```